# Как поставить картинку на фон сайта на определенное место?

Tags: html, изображения, css

Здравствуйте.

Например, у меня есть картинка 400х400, хотелось бы поставить на правый вверхный угол сайта, а на левом углу другую картинку 400х400? Как сделать это?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте все картинки одним файлом и поставьте в нужные места, нужные куски, с помощью CSS свойства [background-position](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position)

Answer (score 1):

Можно для одного элемента назначать несколько бекграундов, НО осёл восьмой и ниже версий - не поддерживает такие стили и для него надо отдельно фикс делать. Вот [пример в действии](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/gK3TK/) (IE9, Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari - гуд). Другой способ - это добавить "обёртку" (100% высоты и ширины документа). В body закинуть один БГ, а в обёртку - другой.